# "Nice" or "Well"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it possible to say and is the phrase correct?

"She dresses very nice."

Or should it be

"She dresses very well."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though many native English speakers would say, "She dresses very nice," it isn't grammatical.  "Nice" is an adjective.  Since what is being modified is the verb "dresses," the proper way to say that is, "She dresses very nicely."  That's because "nicely" is the adverbial form of the word.

"She dresses very well" is grammatical because "well" is an adverb.  If you were to instead say "good," that would not be grammatical because "good" is the adjectival form the word, which isn't to say that you still wouldn't hear many native speakers say it that way, though hopefully far fewer than would say "well."

Comment: In the given context, *nice* = *nicely*.

Comment: I removed a sentence from your answer: *Neither of those is correct.  You must delete the word "is" out of both.*. When I read it, I downvoted it. Then I saw that you must have answered *before* the question was edited by Kris. After that edit, your sentence was out of place. I removed my downvote and gave you an upvote after removing the sentence. ;) Feel free to change it if I did something you didn't want.

Comment: So you wouldn't say something like "the idea loomed large in his mind"? Which is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: @Jason Bassford -- Thanks for the edit.  I did post my answer before Kris edited the question, which then made the first sentence of my answer not make any sense.  I didn't catch this and accidentally rolled back your change, but then I immediately caught it and rolled it back in.  Sorry about that.  Anyway, much a appreciation because  I do hate to look like a dollophead and so wish people, albeit well-intended, wouldn't come and change a question to make already-posted answers look wrong, but what can you do?